# Add year to question and answer dates

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, dates

Seeing as how SO's one year anniversary is coming soon, question and answer dates are going to need to display the year.

Comment: They're probably holding off on it until it's absolutely necessary. Remember with the bounty system, they didn't code the seven-day auto-accept until a couple of days after they rolled out the bounty system itself.

Comment: The yearling badge is probably not even programmed in :)

Comment: Olafur: Maybe in 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already implemented.  I should have searched [uservoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/131779-show-year-in-field-date-asked-) first.

Comment: it is implemented but dormant in the code until dates are >= 360 days from the original dates.

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 9):

If you hover the tool tip does show the year.

Currently in the non-tool tip display it displays:

- seconds ago
- minutes ago
- hours ago
- yesterday
- Month Day at Time

I believe it would be good to show: DD/MM/YYYY (or some variant thereof) after the question is a year old.

Comment: So it does. The information is there, they just haven't made it very visible yet.

Comment: Greasemonkey + jQuery: $("span.relativetime").each(function(){$(this).html($(this).attr("title"));});

Comment: Nice. Now if only the date format was something sensible... Personally I'd like 30.6.2009 23:35 UTC, but ISO 8601 (2009-06-30) would be fine too.

Answer (score 6):

How do you know it just doesn't hide the year if it is in the same year as the question anyway?

Comment: Better to ask rather than assume :)

Comment: Good point.  It's quite possible this is already taken care of.

Comment: It has been answered on UV that it is already implemented and will show up when the site passes a year old.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

- Relative times (5 minutes 28 seconds ago) for questions under x-minutes
- HH:MM:SS questions within 24 hours

And full dates beyond that.