# Shouldn't answers marked as "accepted" rise to the top of the list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote ordering of accepted answers has changed: Accepted below top voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/vote-ordering-of-accepted-answers-has-changed-accepted-below-top-voted)

I have a case where I asked a question and received an answer that I upvoted (because it was helpful, even though it ultimately wasn't the solution to my problem). Later, I figured out the true answer on my own, and marked that as "accepted". Now, when I open this question, it shows the upvoted answer before the accepted answer. Shouldn't the accepted answer always be the first one people see after reading a question?

Comment: If you accept your own answer, it does not change the ordering: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/vote-ordering-of-accepted-answers-has-changed-accepted-below-top-voted

Answer (score 1):

If you accept your own answer it doesn't get listed first, but left in what ever position it occupies in the oldest/newest/votes list.

Comment: Sorry, I did attempt to search for this but missed that post. My case is similar to the one of your blog post. You post some code that isn't working. Later, you realize it was some little setting or minor thing you were doing wrong. The code you posted is actually fine. Why shouldn't your answer that basically says "nothing to see here folks!" be at the top? It's stupid for people to read a question, sift through a bunch of answers, then go, oh, it wasn't really a problem after all.

Comment: @DanThMan: don't post that as an answer. Edit your **question** to include it. That'll put it at the top above *all* answers!

Comment: I did that also, but I wasn't sure people would see the edit since it was a pretty long question (lots of code), so I also included an answer to create a visually separate explanation. Some people read part of a question, read some answers, come back to the question, etc. (I know I'm guilty of that :)). Whatever people are doing, they shouldn't have to scroll down through other answers to see the accepted one, no matter what the circumstance. For the rare instance where the highest voted answer is actually a better answer, it will at worst be in position #2.

Comment: @DanThMan: you could edit it in at the *top* of your question, and use a horizontal rule (markdown: `---`) to separate it from the rest of the question. Please, reserve the use of answers for actual... answers.