# Answer with more upvotes appears above accepted answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

The highest-voted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321) has three votes, and appears above the accepted answer (two votes). I think it's an amusing coincidence that it just so happens to be a Jon Skeet answer. What's going on here? Shouldn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c/268545#268545) be at the top?

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365

Comment: +1 freehand circles.

Comment: When I saw Jon Skeet's score of "only 99.3K" in the screenshot, I knew this question was asked a LONG time ago.  :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the asker accepts his/her own answer, it is not floated to the top.

Comment: Son of a...I didn't even notice it was the same user. *goes and edits his own answer*

Comment: To be honest, opened the question in a new tab, posted this, and then confirmed it...:)

Answer (score 3):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

read in chronological order