# Is it OK to add links or images for new users who cannot?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

it's my understanding that new users can't post more than one link, in order to avoid SPAM. I assume the same is true for images. Can/should we as editors override these restrictions for in cases where we feel it's beneficial? For example, [adding a second link here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2869081/revisions) or [linking the two screen captures here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2867346/revisions)?

Comment: (Yes I realize this is my second `[editing][etiquette]` question today, please don't beat me!)

Comment: I'd much rather see questions of clarification on etiquette then someone that sets some jacked up trend that takes months to undo.

Comment: Thanks @squillman that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, LOL. I *believe* I'm doing the right thing but am just making sure :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say, definitely.

Comment: You wouldn't just say, "No"? :-) (Answer will be accepted in 9 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine.  As you say, the reason for prohibiting low-rep users from posting links and images is fear of spam.  If you read the question and decide that it's okay to post the link/image, then there's no fear of the link/image being part of a scripted spam attack*.

**Unless you are Skynet, in which case we have bigger problems anyways.*

Comment: How did you know I am Skynet??? [Obligatory xkcd](http://xkcd.com/534/)

Comment: Oh, yeah, because I want to feed your already-significant machine learning abilities even more data.  Er, that is, I, for one, welcome our new robot overlords.

Comment: `Syntax Error near "already-significant machine learning abilities"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe one drawback to this is that, if the new user then edits their own question, the images or links *may* be removed again if they still don't have enough Rep to avoid the restrictions.

Comment: Will they? If so, is that a bug?

Comment: There was an issue that turned up a few weeks back, where a user's post had a link, and it was closed as a duplicate which blocked that user from being able to edit it without either removing his own link, or the duplication link.

Answer (score -7):

No

Comment: *[IMPORTANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994405.aspx): READ CAREFULLY. For downvoting purposes only. Do not expose to direct sunlight. NOTE: IF YOU DO NOT HAVE A VALID EULA FOR STACKOVERFLOW YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED TO DOWNVOTE, FLAG OR OTHERWISE USE THE ANSWER COMPONENTS AND YOU HAVE NO RIGHTS UNDER THIS SUPPLEMENTAL EULA.*

Comment: Dang, right when I ran out of votes.

Comment: LOL @voyager. And I was trying to find a clever way to say nothing but "Why" in a comment, and beat the 15 char minimum!

Comment: @Josh: providing all possible answers for a question [is a](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/should-the-system-automatically-modify-the-accepted-answer-when-another-answer-is/24406#24406) [tradition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41313/does-it-cost-rep-to-downvote-a-community-wiki-post/41316#41316) ;)