# Should there be a tab to see anwers with much higher votes than the accepted-answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I know there was a question in which the community responded "higher voted answers should NOT be automatically re-chosen as the users selected answer".

[This is the Post I am referring to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/should-the-system-automatically-modify-the-accepted-answer-when-another-answer-is)

This I agree with. However, it would be really helpful to know when this is occurring in my own accepted answers since they do change over time. I can't seem to find any posts or links to this type of list. Has this been discussed? If so, what was the outcome?

Comment: On Meta, downvotes generally indicate disagreement with your question's premise, not that your question was unclear or not useful.  By convention, questions on Meta are generally beaten senseless by community answers.  If they can survive that treatment, then the proposed idea is generally considered a good one. :)

Comment: "it would be really helpful to know when this is occurring in my own accepted answers since they do change over time". I don't understand what this means, can you clarify?

Comment: If the answer accepted was true at the time accepted, but later another answer was provided and was better suited to answer the question at hand, wouldn't it be helpful to have all; original question, the accepted answer and the community voted on answer re-reviewed by the original poster to provide a chance of modifying the accepted answer? At least, this is what I am trying to get at. Possibly this mechanism exists and I am just not aware of it. For example, @kiamlaluno provides a way for the user to notice this, but it doesn't sound like an obvious way to make it really stand out.

Answer (score 9):

No, there should *not* be a tab for higher voted answers than the accepted, because it is another thing to clutter up the interface...

Besides, **there is already a tab for votes**.

[image]

As you can see above, if you click the `votes` tab, it will sort the answers by having the most votes, with the accepted answer at the top (as the green checkmark acts as an "ultimate" vote of sorts), and then the rest sorted below by the number of votes.  So if you ignore the first accepted answer, the list will show you which answers have more votes (if any) than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the purpose of having such tab.
What would you do when you see which of your answers have been voted more times than the accepted answer?

Comment: it would be an indicator that there may be a better answer then the one I accepted.

Comment: @Beth Inderwiesche For your questions, you already get in the Super-Collider drop-down menu when a user adds an answer; if you look at the new answers when they are reported, then you should know if there better answers. Apart that, the most voted answer is shown right after the accepted one, when you select the "votes" tab right before the answer list. I don't think it is usual to keep changing an accepted answer, then.