# Answer order when asker answers his/her own question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answer-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer with more upvotes appears above accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23049/answer-with-more-upvotes-appears-above-accepted-answer)

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/72112/mouse-clicks-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu) on SU, the asker answered his own question, but the answer didn't get bumped to the top, even though the "votes" tab is active.  If I click the "votes" tab, it re-orders the answers.  Bug?

Comment: When you accept your own answer it doesn't get moved to the top of the answers list. This has been discussed before - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23049/answer-with-more-upvotes-appears-above-accepted-answer