# Sort answer with most votes over accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, voting, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn’t the answer with more votes be above the accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111230/shouldnt-the-answer-with-more-votes-be-above-the-accepted-answer)

**The Problem**

Sometimes the accepted answer isn't the best one. But the accepted answer is always the first. Every user will read it even if it's wrong. If the accepted answer is long the user will not see that there is a better answer.

This happens because of inactive, unknowing or simply lazy users.

**Why do I ask this again?**

I know this topic came up before:

- [Would it be possible to have a "community accepted" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)
- [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users)

One of the [highest voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80321/177555) is saying:

> The "accepted answer" feature was never intended to mark which answer
>   is best or even if the answer is correct. (...)

But at the moment the accepted answer is displayed at the top like it is the best and correct solution. So the problem still exists and I would like to offer a different solution:

**Solution**

Simply sort the answers by votes without placing the accepted answer at the top. Maybe additionally add a notification at the top answer that there is also an accepted answer. (In some rare cases the accepted answer is better.)

This way no new feature must be included. It is a minor change. For most questions this does not change anything at all because most of the time the accepted answer has the highest votes. This way the OP still has the control over what he prefers but the community has a higher influence.

Comment: But the accepted answer is (theoretically) the one that solved the problem.

Comment: Is it really that cumbersome to look past the accepted answer? (Note: I think even this proposal is a dupe, but I can't seem to find it. :s )

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards True and that is why it is highlighted with a checkmark. But this only works if the user rechecks the question for new/better solutions regularly. Also the OP need to know what is better. The community does both.

Comment: Correct, this is a duplicate. Did not see that, sorry. I posted [my point of view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161172/177555) there.