# What to do when someone is evidently biased and wrong?

Tags: discussion

There is this question that kind of worries me. The "accepted" answer is the answer written by the author of the article which caused in the first place the confusion about "Opengl being a 2d api" ...

Here: [Why does this state that WebGL is a 2D API, not a 3D API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135210/webgl-is-2d-api-not-3d-api/13173831#13173831)

I think that the accepted answer is really misleading and close to be plainly wrong. What really bugs me up is that the author of the article is self answering a question that initially caused confusion. Many people already answered with great counter arguments but the user persist to believe that he is right.

I plan to add a new answer to this question to give some more arguments against the idea that opengl is a 2d API.

I believe that even if this question is based on facts, it could be closed with "mainly opinion based" because someone cannot accept to be wrong and ignores all the arguments that other users are giving out.

Comment: Downvote and move on? You cannot force someone to change their opinion, but you *can* vote on the post.

Comment: We certainly should **not** close a question just because someone posted an answer that is wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A question shouldn't be answered based on "opinion"

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Why not? A question should certainly not invite opinions, but if someone chooses to answer an otherwise good question with an opinion heavy answer, just downvote it and move on.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: Why not? As long as the question can be answered with supporting facts, doesn't mean we shoud close it just because someone posted an answer that is wrong. Should I post an opinionated but wrong answer on all your questions just so that they can all be closed?

Comment: I'm not saying the question should be closed but if you look at the comments. It was getting hot at some point.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Then... flag the comments and move on?

Comment: @Yannis there is no flag for "Someone is wrong on the internet"

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix But there is for "getting a bit hot", its either "rude" or "not constructive"

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Touché.

Comment: @RichardTingle I guess yes.

Comment: This post reminds me of http://xkcd.com/386/. Especially of the hidden caption...

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: no, because there is the option to downvote instead. That's what downvotes are *for*. Comments are just comments, if they are getting rude, you flag those and move on. Just not when the only thing about them is that they are wrong.

Comment: Downvote and move on. As some of us are doing to this question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not the first time I see something like that and wish there was something like the "community accepted question" which is pretty much like the question with the most upvotes.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: There already is a feature request for that; most likely it has been marked as declined. Don't conflate the accepted answer with 'best', that is what voting is for.

Comment: The community accepted answer already exists; its the one with the most upvotes

Answer (score 10):

Downvote and comment. If you don't think there is much point in continuing a comment discussion, share the post in the relevant chatroom and ask for the members to have a look at it.

> I believe that even if this question is based on facts, it could be closed with "mainly opinion based" because someone cannot accept to be wrong and ignores all the arguments that other users are giving out.

No, the answers do not make the question closeable. Moderation action is not taken when there are wrong answers, the correct path is to downvote, comment, comment upvote, and possibly share for peer review.

Comment: There is a bounty on it, so "peer review" is pretty useless. It is statement / blog post rather than question as far as I understand it, so it should be closed as unclear what you're asking, but no one can vote to do it now.

Comment: @Mołot Doesn't look that opinionated to me, but the answers have degraded to that. You can request a bounty removal from the mods if you can explain why it is closeable

Comment: I'm not saying it is "opinionated". I just say I can't really see it to be a question. It is plain statement. The only question-type sentence is pretty much answered in question body already.

Comment: @Mołot Ah, I agree on that. Give it a custom flag then :)

Comment: Just did. Got marked helpful, but apparently nothing changed. Well, "not my monkeys, not my circus" ;) did what I could, time to move on.

Comment: @Manishearth - As I commented on my answer, I'm not going to manually remove the bounty, since it's going to expire in five hours anyway. I reworded the question to be an actual question, so it think that it's targeted and relevant enough to stay open.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real problem here is that the accepted answer by default is being sorted ahead of the one with the most votes from the community. Despite s[trong opposition by the community in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161946/rethinking-sort-order-of-answers) to changing this sort order, [I'm beginning to believe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214291/do-accepted-answers-still-serve-a-useful-purpose) that placing the accepted answer at the top is starting to cause more problems than it solves.

There are reasons that the community wants askers to be able to identify the one answer that best solves their problem, but I think we're giving individuals too strong a vote by also making these sort ahead of higher-voted answers by the community. I had to field three flags just yesterday where people were complaining about a wrong answer being sorted ahead of correct ones based on it being incorrectly accepted by the asker.

Leaving a comment explaining why an answer is incorrect, and voting as appropriate is the right way for someone to respond to a seemingly wrong accepted answer, but I think we should reexamine the default sort order that always places accepted answers on top. Conceptually, it seems like a good idea to highlight these answers, but in practice it doesn't always work out so well. For sorting purposes, I think an accept vote should be at best a tiebreaker.

Comment: I disagree a bit - for me the real problem was that OP there posted a statement as a question. If he would look for *answer* and not for *confirmation*, then acceptance check-mark and answer order wouldn't be so problematic. (Note: I don't say if said statement is right or wrong, or which answers are right or wrong). Overall I agree that accepted answer always on top is not the best idea. But I don't think it's the root of the problem right here.

Comment: @Mołot - As an aside, I'm going to let the bounty on that expire in a few hours, rather than remove it. Take a look at the edit I made to the question, which I believe turns it into an actual question about why this statement was made. I think it's now viable in its current state.

Comment: OK, now it is a real question. But I still think that OPs approach was the root of the problem here. For my general thoughts, well, now there is an [answer under your general question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216115/225745).