# On long term: Who is casting more votes on answers supporter or searcher?

Tags: discussion, voting

If you look at older questions on Stackoverflow, that are more than three month old and with more than 1000 views. Sum all votes of all given answers.

Who is casting more votes:

1. Supporter: People who want to help the OP
2. Searcher: People who have the same problem as OP

To identify both groups I would look at the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). Assuming first group is coming from `/questions?sort=active`, `/questions?sort=newest` and similar while second group is coming from google and `/search`.

**Why does it matter?**

This is important to know as base for other discussions. It is key to understand how people use this page to optimize it accordingly. I believe second one is the case but I have met many people here how believe first one is true. Examples from [Mołot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111230/shouldnt-the-answer-with-more-votes-be-above-the-accepted-answer#comment628273_161172), [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111230/shouldnt-the-answer-with-more-votes-be-above-the-accepted-answer#comment467971_161172), [JNK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111230/shouldnt-the-answer-with-more-votes-be-above-the-accepted-answer#comment288379_111232):

- "Do you have any data that shows how high % of voters are from direct entry (probably search engine result) or search"
- "I still trust the person with the actual problem more than random people who read a question"
- "you up vote what practical works for you" isn't true

I picked those comments from only on questions but understand how SO is used should be relevant for other questions, too.

Comment: Why does it matter?  What are you going to do with this information?

Comment: What exactly do you want to discuss here?

Comment: Im just going to put it out there, for questions that old you're going to get 0 people coming from sort=newest and very low coming from sort=active

Comment: The long tail is a long tail. Some of us follow a rabbit hole and vote, others search and vote, others still use related questions. It would be neat to see a breakdown of votes based on referrer.

Comment: I added why I am asking this with example references of people believing otherwise.

Comment: The comments you point to seem to have nothing to do with the question you're asking. Those comments were about whether or not the accepted answer should be sorted above more highly voted answers. Your question is about where the voting traffic for questions comes from. I don't see the connection here.

Comment: Also, there are many questions I've voted up after finding them via a Google search simply because I thought they were well-asked. How I arrived at a question doesn't change how I vote.

Comment: @Brad Larson: The comments are about how is voting, why are they voting and how you could trust them. With this question I try to get statistics about this. Mołot asked for this. Also this is not about votes on questions but on answers.

Comment: @Brad Larson You are talking about your self and poeple here you know. But keep in mind that you are not the typical SO user. You and all people here are a supporter. That is what is difficult about this. As a supporter it might be hard to imaging that most people use SO in this other way as searcher.

Comment: @PiTheNumber I don't see any way at all statistics can help you determine this. A great many active users will come here from Google. And how do you determine what percentage it is who do, anyway? Do you have any idea how frequent Brad and my behavior is here, or any way to determine that?

Comment: @AndrewBarber What is easy to do is analyse referer. More work is to filter out what referer has voted. Sure referer is only an indicator and will not group users 100% correct. To do it reliable you would need to analyse a users activity history. But that would be quite some work and I don't like to make to much trouble. I just would like to understand how people use the page.

Comment: @pi I visit from Google all the time. Referer tells you almost nothing.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Do you search in Google for questions you want to answer or do you search for a problem you have?

Comment: @pithe Problems. And now I sort of see your point :)

Comment: I Google to get answers (because SO search leaves much to be desired and might not have the answer), I browse SO to provide answers. Who would Google for questions to answer? That makes little to no sense to me. I don't know if that helps at all. This discussion seems split between two opposing points, but then again, I haven't read 2 consecutive sentences yet.