# Change text about "rise to the top" on the tour page

Tags: feature-request, wording, tour

https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour

> [image]

1. The order is dependent on selected sort option.
2. Only accepted answer always shown first regardless of sorting choice.

So, maybe we need to change this text?

Comment: BTW, the accepted answer may not be the topmost answer if it's a self-accepted answer written by the OP. At least, that's the case on SO; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261634/why-is-the-accepted-answer-not-on-top

Answer (score 2):

If the majority of visitors are not logged-in users, the fact that you can tweak the display if you are logged in is of little consequence. I feel that the text adequately describes the site's expected behavior for the majority of users.

Being correct in the details would merely obscure the basic principle. Those who actually read this text are not going to care about what to them is esoteric expert knowledge.

The mechanism described in the text also applies more broadly; posts with many votes are more likely to be returned as a top search result both on the site itself and in search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Observation: # 1. The order is dependent on selected sort option.

The ability to choose offers more flexibility, of course choosing the newest answer out of many older answers may not result in the first answer having the most upvotes nor being the best; it's not the default sort order, see below.

Observation: # 2. Only accepted answer always shown first regardless of sorting choice.

The entirety of that quote is:

> 1. This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
>      Just questions...
>      ...and answers
> 2. `Good answers are voted up and`**`rise to the top.`**
>      `The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.`
> 3. The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".
>      Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.

The explanation behind that is offered in the Q&A: "[Can we exempt downvoted accepted answers from getting the top spot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178439/282094)", in [shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189424/282094):

> "First off, excellent suggestion, thanks for writing this up. We discussed this extensively internally, and while I'm declining it right now I don't think it's without merit — it's just not something we think is worth the added complexity right now.
>
> ...
>
> ... we provide the folks asking questions with a built-in way to say "thanks" — the ability to "accept" an answer. This isn't predicated on reputation or experience, but rather on the simple fact that you had a problem and someone tried to help you solve it.
>
> By default, Stack Exchange uses a very simple ranking system for answers. An answer's score is upvotes-downvotes, with higher-scored answers appearing first in the default sort order.
>
> … Except when there is an accepted answer. Then it always appears first. Regardless of sort order. This one little inconsistency was added as a way to highlight the importance of an answer which is presumed to have actually helped at least one person ...
>
> ...

> Question: So, maybe we need to change this text?

What is quoted on the [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) is a set of summaries of [key points](https://www.copyblogger.com/writing-bullet-points/).

Over the years many have made various complaints and like your question have offered no clear improvement or text that has been adopted; so we have the existing text and no suggested improved text.

Similar questions:

- [Banner claim “The best answers are voted up and rise to the top” is not true [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220712/282094)
- [Shouldn't the answer with more votes be above the accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111230/282094)
- [Rethinking sort order of answers [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161946/282094)

We welcome a *better* answer. A great way forward that respects both the asker for providing the specific question that survived closure and need for further improvement, the one whom provided the *best* answer for the asker, and that ranks the efforts of others (as reviewed by the community, through edits, votes, or flags).

If someone could say: "Why not simply ..." that would be great, but after several years this is what we have, and your question only suggests to change things; perhaps you have an answer too. It can be easy to say something is wrong but more difficult to prove what is better.

Your *benefit* from the current system is that anyone can provide an answer, everyone can vote on it, but you get to choose which one of them you think answers your question better than any other answers.

A similar problem arises if there are two equally great answers, you can only choose one.