# Why is the accepted answer at the end?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote ordering of accepted answers has changed: Accepted below top voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/vote-ordering-of-accepted-answers-has-changed-accepted-below-top-voted)

See this question : [JQuery UI datepicker not sitting over dropdowns in IE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840117/jquery-ui-datepicker-not-sitting-over-dropdowns-in-ie-6)

The accepted answer is all the way to the bottom, displayed in a random order. Is that a bug or a feature?

If it's a feature... why?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the asker answered the question himself.

In this case, the accepted answer keeps its original sort order.

Comment: Ok. I'm not a big fan of the accepted answer being all the way to the end, but makes sense. Thanks!