# Accepted answer not listed as first answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

#### Issue Description

When viewing a question where the accepted answer has the same score as non-accepted answers, the accepted answer does not appear first in the list.

#### Example

Viewing [this question on the Gaming SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14142/when-do-i-get-a-bigger-office-and-can-employ-more-people) and refreshing it will result in the accepted answer migrating up and down the list. Note that the sort order is by *votes*. Reproducable on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799395/why-is-notice-not-showing-after-redirect-in-rails-3/4799630) as well.

[image: gaming @ stack exchange]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accepted self-answers do not appear at the top of the list; this is intentional as per [Vote ordering of accepted answers has changed: Accepted below top voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/vote-ordering-of-accepted-answers-has-changed-accepted-below-top-voted)

Comment: A-ha! Nice catch. Thanks for the tip.