# Why is an accepted answer displayed lower than another (more upvoted) answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182278/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-the-c-friend-concept-in-java), a non-accepted answer (the one with 27 upvotes) is placed above the accepted one (with 20 upvotes).  I quickly checked some other questions and found that this behavior wasn't occurring elsewhere.  Is this a bug, or is this some SO feature that I'm missing?

[image: img]

Comment: Because the OP is the author. See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6366/180794