# Year missing from post dates

Tags: support

First, I love SO.
But, how can someone know how old a question is if the year is missing from all the dates?  It seems important to know how old a question is.  Am I missing it somehow? Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SO hasn't been around for a year yet. When it has been, the year will be visible in the dates. (It's actually already there in the mouseover text.)

See also [Add year to question and answer dates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates).

Comment: Whoa! Didn't know that!

Answer (score 4):

it is implemented but dormant in the code until dates are >= 360 days from the original dates.