# Add Year to Dates for Dates within 11 Months

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, dates

**Note:** I know this is very similar to "[Add year to question and answer dates.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates)". I felt it deserved a separate question because I'm asking for a modification to the functionality requested in that question, and because that one is tagged <kbd>status-completed</kbd> and this one is not completed.

---

I find I have some issues with the current implementation of date display. Although it is obviously necessary to include the year with a date > 1 year ago, I think it should be added for every date > 11 months ago.

For instance, today is Aug 19, 2009.

```
Date           Display  
Aug 16, 2008   Aug 16 08  
Aug 16, 2009   Aug 16  
Aug 26, 2008   Aug 26
```

This leaves August 16, 2009 looking a lot like August 26, 2008. I dislike the fact that I have to stop and reason that today is the 19<sup>th</sup>, and that 26 `>` 19, so that "Aug 26" must be last year.

Comment: For some reason I remember this request...

Comment: ...and here's why, dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/date-formatting-on-questions-and-answers

Comment: It makes so much more sense, now that it says 11 months, instead of 13.

Comment: delete

Comment: Should be 10 months, surely? What if it is 31st August and a question says "1st September"?

Comment: I haven't experienced that problem yet. It seemed to me that my problem was from seeing two dates with "Aug" - I didn't want to have to stop and do math on the day of month in order to know if it was the same year or not. I don't know that I'll have the same problem with next-month-over.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm not sure what the `status-completed` tag means in this instance. Can you clarify?