# Add year to time date stamps

Tags: feature-request, timestamps, dates, date-format

Throughout the site abbreviated dates are used (Apr 21 at 9:12). This works great for dates within the current year but it seems that as the years roll by it'll become important to include the year in the date. I am not sure that having the time is of value for a post that is a year old. Maybe at a certain threshold replacing the time with the year is appropriate.

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15576/add-year-to-dates-for-dates-within-11-months

Comment: if you really want the year all the time, you can tweak this greasemonkey script.  it'll even show it in local time if you want.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/greasemonkey-script-to-display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time

Comment: Related: [Display the year in the inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222811/display-year-in-the-inbox-message-date-stamp) for older messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dates more than a year old do include the year. See for example: [While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4)

Comment: Very cool - had not seen that before!

Comment: But not --- as shown in that example, on the date of an *edit*.

Comment: @Richard: That edit was *this* year.

Answer (score 8):

Hover over the time stamp and you'll see the UTC time as a tool tip.

[Tool Tip http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/1673/tooltipg.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/1673/tooltipg.png)

Comment: Yes and you can actually hover over almost any day type thing and get a precise date.

Comment: Hover over UI element is unfortunately not a solution for touch-based devices, and their market share is rapidly increasing, with [more than 1/3 of American adults owning a tablet computer](http://www.pewinternet.org/2013/06/10/tablet-ownership-2013/).