# Display year in the inbox message date stamp

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, date-format

Here's a screenshot of my inbox:

[image]

It's obvious that Feb 8 doesn't refer to 2014, but it's not obvious to what year it actually refers to.

Adding the year explicitly to older messages would help [locate message of interest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94779/how-do-we-see-the-private-messages-that-moderators-sent-us/222812#222812) faster. Right now, the year is only visible as a tooltip when mousing over, which isn't an option for touch-based devices (which represent a huge market share, with over 1/3 of American adults owning a tablet computer in June 2013).

Comment: Huh, I thought we had a thing where the year is shown if it's not the *latest of that month* but in that case, that's 2010 and 2011 dates, so... guess that's not in place here either.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the inbox tab of the network profile doesn't do this at all – I checked by looking at the oldest page there, where the notifications are from 2017 but that year isn't indicated on that tab.