# All posts need full YYYY datestamp in order for archive to be helpful

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface, revisions-list

I have been using stackoverflow for a while, coming in from google without logging in. The content is truly helpful.

The worst part about the site, though, is the usage of "time ago" instead of a real datestamp. It is maddening to know that, for example, software X was released on Y date [ie YYYY.mmdd format] and have to mentally compare the Stackoverflow unformatted date [ie such as 
"6 months and 5 days ago"].

A number of us seem to consider this a bug, but I did not see my specific problem scenario described. So, in hopes of change, here it is!

There are a few related questions here, such as:
See [Add year to question and answer dates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates) .

Comment: declined because the year already shows on posts older than a year and because you can already see the date in a tooltip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just hover over most dates to see the UTC (Z or Zulu) time.

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/9750/datecursortooltiphover.png

Comment: Thank you for the picture, Jeff, and to everyone else for replies :).

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a tooltip associated with the 'time ago' value, which shows the UTC time and date of the post.

Just move your cursor near the value to see the tool tip.