# When can I start seeing 2019 in the date?

Tags: support, timestamps, dates

I’ve noticed the obvious pattern from an edit in a question. First, it displays the number of hours, days etc. After a couple of days (?) it begins to display the actual date of posting.

I seem to not have been paying attention in 2018. Does the year only make itself present once it has gone, or is there a waiting period? Do I have to wait until 2020?

Comment: You have to wait until 2020.  The implication is that a date without a year means this year.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *used* to be shown only on dates [360 days, almost a full year, ago or older](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2470/295232), but this has changed: now it's shown on [all timestamps not belonging to the current calendar year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171295/295232). So you have to wait until 2020-01-01.

If you can't wait, note that hovering over most (all?) timestamps (relative or absolute) will always show the full timestamp, including the year:

[image]

Comment: It is definitely not all timestamps. Suspension notices don't show the exact timestamp on hover for example.