# The date display for the current year is ambiguous. Please fix it

Tags: feature-request, answers, information-display, dates

[image]

[Screenshot of this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/104661/318).

It says "Jan 11".

Is that Jan 11th of this year? Or January of 2011? I have been on Stack Overflow since 2008 and I have no idea when [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) started, so it's not far-fetched that I asked a question in 2011.

It's too ambiguous. Add an ordinal suffix to make Jan 11 into Jan 11th. Or add the year: Jan 11 2020. Or use European style: 11 Jan 2020.

Or just use the same style for every date: "answered Oct 15 '18" like [this answer in the same thread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/92907/318). I would only know that Jan 11 means "this year" by looking at other answers from different years (if there are any).

Comment: If you don't see an apostrophe and a two-digit year proceeding it, it's the current calendar year.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1306/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221655/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321873/282094 etc.

Comment: There isn't a single European style, though they are in strict significance order (usually least first, but [Wikipedia claims both orders are officially accepted in many places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)). E.g., there are different delimiters: space, `.`, `-`, and `/`. It would be more correct to say in the-rest-of-us order (the rest of the world).

Comment: Sonic's comment nearly got it right: it's an apostrophe *before* the last two digits of the year (For non-native speakers: it's neither "proceed" nor "precede", the most appropriate term should have been  *…and a two-digit year "following" it*)

Comment: Still... when a post is over 6 months old, omitting '20 on the timestamp, is *weird*. I wouldn't do it in any report or paper so why does Stack Exchange?

Comment: I blame the Y2K

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog I explained in my request why it's ambiguous

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate but the other request is **6 years old**. Is there no time limit on duplicates? If it's 6 years old it's very likely to not get any more upvotes. Man, this was a big waste of time.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, there's no time limit when it comes to closing as duplicates of prior requests that haven't had any staff response yet. However, not all hope is lost, and there are ways to get official attention for older requests, which I've used in the past and have worked. See [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](/a/306398).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see something like this:

[image]

It's the current year.  Also, the code to show the year doesn't activate until more than 360 days after the post was posted, so to see the exact date before those 360 days, hover over the "asked X time ago".

As for *why*, the dates are thought to be recent enough so that you don't need to be reminded, until >=360 days.

Comment: Is the 360 day thing new? I remember that in the past, everything from previous calendar years would show the abbreviated year, so when a new year came everything would show with an abbreviated year except for posts just made that year.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Nope, [t'isn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates#comment8301_2470).  Or doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Things may have changed since 2009, though. Half the time, posts from then are inaccurate due to changes that took place in the early 2010s.

Comment: If an answer or question has been posted between January and June, is it still *recent* enough?  On the Internet?

Comment: I explained in my initial post why this wasn't clear from the UI. You have to look at other answers to figure it out. It's an unclear UX and that's why I think it should be changed.

Comment: @jcollum Not for me. I kinda figured it out by instinct.

Comment: Figuring it out by instinct only works for the people who actually manage that. You shouldn't assume other people will do that so making it less ambiguous is preferable.

Comment: @jcollum but it seems most people are fine with it. features requests should only be implemented when a lot of people have the same problem.

Comment: looks to me like they actually implemented this